# Best way to mock window object with location.href changes in Jest?

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs

I have a function that redirects the window if certain conditions are met.

To test it, I need to mock the window object, however I am unable to modify the `window.location.href` value, either within the test or within the function I am testing.

I am getting `Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)`

This is within **Angular 5**

Answer (score 0):

Better than modifying the window.location would be to inject Angulars Location: https://angular.io/api/common/Location
This would then also allow you to mock it as you're used to with other providers!